# Get Url of attachment (IMessage.Attachments)

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to code a chat-log function into my bot. I know of `IMessage.Attachments`, but I don't know how to actually use it.

I don't have my exact code on hand (for now), but it looks like this:

```
_client.MessageReceived += async (message) =>
        {
            var attach = message.Attachments.Url as IMessage; //get Url of attachment
            if ('message contains attachment (?)' && !message.Author.IsBot)
                await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Attachment: " + attach); //send attachment
        };
```

Of course, that doesn't work. The documentation didn't really help me either. It would be nice if someone could explain this to me.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this:

```
message.Attachments.FirstOrDefault().Url
```